# Export ".maj" file using forge api

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, revit-api

We are looking to export ".maj" file from Revit file using forge api's.

Can you please suggest us the best fit forge api to download the ".maj" file from revit file?

We are investigating whether forge design automation(DA) api will be useful. There are certain steps we need to perform to export .maj file with Revit desktop application. https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/revit/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2018/ENU/Revit-AddIns/files/GUID-64DABB5B-8FEA-4827-B29E-993EF72D85C6-htm.html.
In which we need add-in "Fabrication extension for a Revit" We are looking if this extension is supported by DA for a Revit. Can you please confirm same?

Answer (score 0):

No, the fabrication extension is not supported by the APS Design Automation for Revit API. Sorry for the bad news.